# Disable or change keyboard shortcut for trash

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, trash

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16 and I want to disable or change the shortcut which opens the Trash, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. I already looked in **keyboard shortcuts** and I couldn't locate this shortcut. I even searched in compizconfig but still nothing.